# Why is my "access grant malformed" in Azure AD?

Tags: python, azure, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to get single sign-on working in Azure Active Directory, using [this bit of documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn645542.aspx) as a guide. However, when I get up to the "access token request" stage, I get the following error:

> Error validating credentials. AADSTS70000: The provided access grant is invalid or malformed.

Searching the Internet, it seems that this is usually caused by the `redirect_uri` parameter being missing in the second step or different between the two steps, but that doesn't seem to be the case here.

Here's what's happening in each step:

Authorize step (raw HTTP request from browser):

```
GET /[snip tenant id]/oauth2/authorize?redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A5000%2Fpost-login%3Fdest%3D%252F&response_type=code&client_id=[snip client id] HTTP/1.1
Host: login.windows.net
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.71 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-AU,en;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6
Cookie: [snip a handful of cookies]
```

Redirect step (raw HTTP request from browser):

```
GET /post-login?code=[snip base64]&session_state=[snip uuid] HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:5000
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.71 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-AU,en;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6
Cookie: csrftoken=vBjLMAFTw7NSFEJHb2t9GTA0Eoced4rw; azure-redirect-uri="http://localhost:5000/post-login?dest=%2F"
```

Token request step (raw HTTP request from server code):

```
POST /[snip tenant id]/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: login.windows.net
Content-Length: 805
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: */*
User-Agent: python-requests/2.5.0 CPython/2.7.6 Darwin/14.0.0
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A5000%2Fpost-login%3Fdest%3D%252F&client_secret=Dsysz7F%2FXh2Wu1YKE%2BVEOkvMHhvc38DnwFTa5qekyXM%3D&code=[snip base64]&client_id=[snip client id]&grant_type=authorization_code
```

Response to token request (Python dict parsed from JSON returned):

```
{
    u'timestamp': u'2014-12-09 05:37:58Z', 
    u'trace_id': u'ae00a782-30f1-4e1c-a183-f19330ecca37',
    u'submit_url': None, 
    u'correlation_id': u'21a7b861-5171-4083-9da5-67e7d956ab5e',
    u'error_description': u'AADSTS70002: Error validating credentials. AADSTS70000: The provided access grant is invalid or malformed.\r\nTrace ID: ae00a782-30f1-4e1c-a183-f19330ecca37\r\nCorrelation ID: 21a7b861-5171-4083-9da5-67e7d956ab5e\r\nTimestamp: 2014-12-09 05:37:58Z',
    u'context': None, 
    u'error': u'invalid_grant',
    u'error_codes': [70002, 70000]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your token request is failing because of the query parameter at the end of your redirect uri.  OAuth redirect URI's should not have any query parameters or fragments.  You can use the state parameter instead.

I don't think that the authorize call should have succeeded either, but clearly it did.  I am checking to see if that is a bug.

See this link for some more information on how to use the OAuth state parameter:

http://www.thread-safe.com/2014/05/the-correct-use-of-state-parameter-in.html

Comment: That worked, with the addition that the `redirect_uri` must be an *exact* match to what is in the Azure config panel. The reason this threw me is, if the `redirect_uri` is totally different (e.g. `http://example.com/` vs `http://example.org/`) the authorize step fails, but if the `redirect_uri` in the request is a subpath of what's configured in the panel (e.g. `http://example.com/foo` vs `http://example.com/`) the authorize step succeeds and the token step fails. (Also, in the first case the error message mentions the `redirect_url` specifically, but not in the second.) Anyway, thanks!